# Django breadcrumb html tag define list in include tag

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to for loop the names with bclist in breadcrumb.html

`{% include 'breadcrumb.html' with bcTitle=category.name bcList=["test","tester"] %}`

breadcrumb.html:

```
{% for i in bcList %}
    <li class="breadcrumb-item" aria-current="page">{{ i }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as there are no spaces in the breadcrumb names:

```
{% with '1 2 3' as list %}
  {% for i in list.split %}
    {{ i }}<br>
  {% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: Great, so can i send two variables instead of list?
Example:

{% with category.title, category.sub.title as list %}

Comment: And i will also using this format: {% with category.title + "main title" as list %}